# ModeShape with PicketLink security?

Tags: security, jboss, jcr, modeshape, picketlink

We have standardized on JBoss PicketLink as our Authentication, Authorization, and Identity Management framework and use it throughout our enterprise applications.  Now, we would like to integrate JBoss ModeShape as a content management repository into one of our applications.  Is there a way to have ModeShape leverage the PicketLink `Identity`, `Roles`, `Groups`, etc. in its authentication and authorization decisions?  I would hope that since they're both JBoss projects the integration would be easy, but I haven't found any documentation around how to configure it.